# C++ Printing Time Only to a file!

Tags: c++, file-io, time

How can I print only the current time (not the date) to a file?  I need it in this format...

13:55:36

I've tried a few different ideas but they all include the date too.

Comment: I figured it out...This method worked...Thx anyways!

string kimsCache::getCurrentTime()
{
   time_t rawtime;
   struct tm * timeinfo;

   time ( &rawtime );
   timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
   char buffer [9];
   strftime(buffer, 9, "%X", timeinfo);
   return buffer;
}

Answer (score 2):

Try perusing [this ctime reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/)

A combination of using `time()`, `localtime()`, `strftime()`, and the `struct tm` should get you there

Answer (score 1):

Try [strftime()](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strftime/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [**strftime**](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime)!  There is a code example on that page showing how to prepare for use of this function using time(), localtime()...

```
char timestring[12];
strftime(timestring,sizeof(timestring),"%T",timestruct);
puts(timestring);
```